# Apachesolr sort based on nodeviewcount

Tags: search, 7

I need to provide the option for sorting on the basis of nodeviewcount.
The criteria is that if any text is provided for search, the search results will be displayed according to maximum number of nodes viewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Apache Solr View Count](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_viewcount) module which does exactly the same.

> This module allows you to index the node view count to Apache solr
>   index as a custom field and let you sort SOLR results. The module
>   requires Apache solr search module.

Disclosure: I'm one of the module maintainer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I check whether it is working fine for me and inform you.

Comment: It is not working fine. Node view count is increasing, But when i am searching the results are not showing properly.

Comment: I would like to know. Once enabled, will the option displays in settings of apache sort.

Comment: There were some issue in nodeviewcount due to which it was not working fine. Once I updated the module. It worked fine. Thanks for help.

Comment: Another thing to note is the node view count needs to be indexed in apachesolr. So the changes will reflect only upon indexing.